# How to add package to cabal2nix generated `env`?

Tags: haskell, cabal, nix, nixos

I use this `default.nix` to build my package with `nix-build` and get the `env` with `nix-shell`

```
{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {} }:
with pkgs;
with haskellPackages;

let
  myPackage = callPackage ./myPackage.nix {};
in
  if lib.inNixShell then myPackage.env else myPackage
```

`myPackage.nix` generated using `cabal2nix . > myPackage.nix`

```
{ mkDerivation, base, split, stdenv }:
mkDerivation {
  pname = "myPackage";
  version = "0.1.0.0";
  src = ./.;
  isLibrary = false;
  isExecutable = true;
  executableHaskellDepends = [ base split ];
  license = stdenv.lib.licenses.bsd3;
}
```

This working fine for building but I want to add development helper tools while I working on it. I don't want to edit `myPackage.nix`. I want to re-run `cabal2nix` when I edit `myPackage.cabal`.

I try to use `buildInputs` of `mkDerivation` but did not seem to work.

```
let
  myPackage = callPackage ./myPackage.nix {};
in
  stdenv.mkDerivation {
    name = myPackage.name;

    buildInputs = [ myPackage hlint hasktags ];
}
```

Beside `nix-build` stop working, it also drop me in the shell with executable of `myPackage` but without `myPackage`'s env.

I know this because `ghc` is not avaliable while it exists in `myPackage`'s env when using `default.nix` above.

How can I add those tools to `env` generated from `cabal2nix` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `nix-shell` commands builds all dependencies of a project, sets all environment variables to their respective derivation attribute values and sources ([bash](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x237.html)) `$stdenv/setup`. For more details, see [the Nix manual about `nix-shell`](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sec-nix-shell).

So in your last example, if you run `echo $buildInputs` you'll see your built package as a build input. So that works, but it's not what you want.

Instead, you need to reuse the Haskell-specific environment derivation, `myPackage.env`. This dummy derivation for `nix-shell` has a GHC that is set up to discover only your dependencies etc.

```
pkgs.lib.overrideDerivation myPackage.env (old: {
    buildInputs = old.buildInputs ++ [ pkgs.haskellPackages.hlint ];
})
```

---

*Unsolicited advice ;)*

In my projects, I use a `shell.nix` file for this. This also lets me avoid the `lib.inNixShell` value that breaks referential transparency.

If your project consists of more than a Haskell package, I recommend writing an overlay. It will make your project much more coherent.

`shell.nix`

```
# This imports the project + overlay. The overlay takes care of
# adding `myPackage` to `haskellPackages`, to make it available
# throughout the project.
attrs@{...}:
let pkgs = (import ../nix attrs);

# Adapt myPackage.env
in pkgs.lib.overrideDerivation pkgs.haskellPackages.myPackage.env (old: {
    buildInputs = old.buildInputs ++ [ pkgs.haskellPackages.hlint ];
})
```

For an example of an overlay, see [zimbatm's todomvc-nix](https://github.com/zimbatm/todomvc-nix/blob/master/nix/default.nix).